# Expose 3G/LTE router LAN to the internet. What are my options?

Tags: networking, router, vpn, proxy, ssh-tunnel

I have a 3G/LTE router in my office (TP-LINK ARCHER MR400). It connects to the internet via a local mobile carrier. This LAN is under NAT (CGNAT?) imposed by the LTE provider.

I want to be able to connect to computers on the LAN from the internet. Eventually, I want to interconnect the router's network with the VPN network and access the combined network via a VPN.

There is no way I can get public IP from the internet provider and I cannot get any help to achieve my goals from them as well.

I'm trying to understand my options and find the best way to expose this LAN to the internet.

I was thinking about:

1. Configuring DDNS on the router. The router supports DDNS but as I understand, because the router's network is under NAT the IP the router will register itself with, will be provider's private network IP and not the public IP so I won't be able to connect to my office LAN from outside.
2. Connecting Google Cloud VPN to the router's network via UPD encapsulation with NAT-T (whatever all of this means :)). But in the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/advanced#udp-encapsulation) it says that only one-to-one NAT is supported. I do not exactly understand the terminology here, but it looks like I won't be able to utilize this method. Please correct me if I'm wrong here. Maybe there is a way to do that with OpenVPN?
3. Spinning up a separate server in Google Cloud and setting up SSH tunneling from specific machines in my office LAN to this server. I was partially successful with this method and was able to connect to computers with a help of http://localhost.run/ service. I can probably replicate such infrastructure on-premise, but I do not understand: a) the security implications of this method and b) how to set up my router and connect the entire network and not just specific machines to the VPN.
4. Having some proxy server and somehow register the router into it. But I do not understand the specifics of how to it and whether this is even possible.

Have I missed any other options? Could you please recommend the best way to achieve my goal?

Comment: I am not at all sure here. Have you considered DynDNS?  dyndns.com

Comment: @John I've tried no-ip.com DDNS but it did not work. I believe no-ip is basically the same as DynDNS. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: My only experience is going the other way (3G client to fixed IP). I have to pay a small monthly upcharge to the ISP to allow me to use VPN.  Does your ISP have this added facility that may help you?

Comment: @John Unfortunately, my ISP does not provide neither VPN nor fixed IP.

Comment: Right now looking into https://www.zerotier.com/ seems like a very good additional option

Comment: Do you have a different ISP nearby that can give you a proper vanilla modem with static IP?

Comment: My set up is in kind of a remote location, only 2 ISPs are viable options. Another one is also 3g/LTE NAT'd network but can give me a fixed IP. The problem with another ISP is that the internet connection is extremely poor. Also, there are no wired internet providers in the area.